# Not able to print logs from static library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, logging, static-libraries

I have created static library. There are several logs present in library, but none of it is getting printed. While, logs from my main application are getting printed correctly in XCode.

I tried to check all the settings, but finding no clue on this.

Please note, I have added logs at very obvious places, but none of it is actually printing.

Comment: What did you use to print log in the library? And it is your own library, right?

Comment: Yes my own lib. I am using NSLog

Comment: I also use my static lib in my project and all the logs are all printed as they were expected to. The only special flags I set in the project's `Build Setting` are `Other Linker Flags = -all_load -ObjC`. Did you set this in yours?

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure out problem.  I am still not able to resolve issue. But I recreated library by adding existing source files and it is working fine now.